# Error while installing truffle framework

Tags: truffle

I've received the following error message while installing truffle framework on my windows 10 device.

> "Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be
>   used."

Can somebody please tell what it means and if there is any way to rectify this error.

Comment: Do you have the full log?

Comment: Have you installed `production windows-build-tools` ?